# passing variables with inheritance

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to practice OOP by making a class selection program

```
    # let's make a character selection program

    class player:
      def __init__(self, username, age, weight, height, gender):
        self.username = username
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.gender = gender

    class soldier(player):
      strength = weight*height*2
      print strength

    print "Please enter the following"

    player_username = raw_input("Please enter a username: ")
    player_age = input("Please enter your age: ")
    player_weight = input("Please enter your weight: ")
    player_height = input("Please enter your height: ")
    player_gender  = raw_input("Please enter your gender: ")
    player_character_class = raw_input("Please enter a player class: ")

    character_obj = player(player_username, player_age, player_weight, player_height, player_gender)
    print soldier.strength
```

However, I get the error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "character_select.py", line 11, in <module>
        class soldier(player):
      File "character_select.py", line 12, in soldier
        strength = weight*height*2
    NameError: name 'weight' is not defined
```

Not really sure how how weight isn't defined. I thought I inherited it by passing "player" into "solder". Could someone help me on this?

Thank you!

Comment: You've not quite yet grasped class inheritance, I fear. The `soldier` class has no methods, for example, nor do you create an instance of it anywhere.

Comment: As a side note, in Python 2, you should always define `class player(object):`, not `class player:`.

Comment: Anyway, `weight` isn't defined because `soldier` only has access to the class attributes of `player`, not to instance attributes of `player` instances that may exist in the future. If that all sounds too confusing, just don't use class attributes, and you won't have to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you assign attributes to your `player` in `__init__()`, they don't get created until `player` is instantiated. However, in your `soldier` class, you're trying to set *class* attributes *at class creation time* based on variables that don't exist at that time, because they only exist on instances (of a different class, no less).

I think what you probably want to do is write an `__init__()` method for `soldier`. (I have also taken the liberty of capitalizing your class names per PEP 8. This helps keep track of which names refer to classes, i.e. *templates* for constructing objects, and which to instances of the classes.)

```
class Soldier(Player):
    def __init__(self, username, age, weight, height, gender):
        # call parent class to set up the standard player attributes
        Player.__init__(self, username, age, weight, height, gender)
        # now also define a soldier-specific attribute
        self.strength = weight*height*2
```

And then *instantiate* the `Soldier` class rather than the `Player` class, since you want a soldier:

```
character_obj = Soldier(player_username, player_age, player_weight, player_height, player_gender)
print character_obj.strength
```

I should further note that this:

```
class Soldier(Player):
```

is *not* a function call. You are not *passing* `Player` to `Soldier`. Instead you are saying that `Soldier` is a *kind of* `Player`. As such, it has all the attributes and capabilities of a `Player` (which you do not need to specify again, that's the whole point of inheritance) plus any additional ones you define in `Soldier`. However, you do not have direct access to the attributes of `Player` (or a `Player` instance) when declaring `Soldier` (not that you would ordinarily need them).

Comment: All good, except that your text says you've taken the liberty of pep8-ifying the names, but your code doesn't actually do so.

Comment: You're right, I didn't.  :-)  Fixed

Comment: +1 for PEP 8 compliance.

Comment: It might be nicer to use `super` here rather than explicitly naming the superclass. Then again, that might just be one more potential source of confusion, so maybe not.

Comment: This might be better written as a property, to save forwarding `__init__`: `class Soldier(Player):` `@property` `def strength(self): return self.weight * self.height * 2`

Comment: Whoever downvoted this… why?

Comment: I think when someone is so confused about OOP that they think they are passing an instance of one class when defining another, we can save `super()` and properties for later. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Soldier is a class, yet you haven't instantiated it anywhere. You've tried instantiating a player, with character_obj, but when you attempt to print soldier.xxx it's looking at the class, not any object.

Answer (score 1):

I took the liberty of correcting some errors/misconceptions in the code - see if this is helpful:

```
# let's make a character selection program

class Player:
    def __init__(self, username, age, weight, height, gender):
        self.username = username
        self.age = age
        self.weight = weight
        self.height = height
        self.gender = gender

class Soldier(Player):
    def __init__(self, *args):
#       First of all, in order to actually inherit the attributes of "player", you need to invoke the __init__ function for "player":
        Player.__init__(self, *args)  # The *args business is to send any arguments that can be handled by the generic player constructor to that player constructor.
#       You probably want to work on the instance variable "strength", so use self.strength, self.weight, and self.height
        self.strength = self.weight*self.height*2
#        print strength

print "Please enter the following"

player_username = raw_input("Please enter a username: ")
player_age = input("Please enter your age: ")
player_weight = input("Please enter your weight: ")
player_height = input("Please enter your height: ")
player_gender  = raw_input("Please enter your gender: ")
player_character_class = raw_input("Please enter a player class: ")

# I'm guessing you actually wanted to make the player a "soldier", not a generic "player"
character_obj = Soldier(player_username, player_age, player_weight, player_height, player_gender)
print character_obj.strength
```

Here is the output:

```
Please enter the following
Please enter a username: Brionius
Please enter your age: 92
Please enter your weight: 50
Please enter your height: 7
Please enter your gender: yes
Please enter a player class: super soldier
700
```